# Open SSH and Telnet behaving strange on windows server 2019 based on timezone of the server

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2019, plink

I have a strange issue when I connect SSH from one of my machines to a windows server 2019
I use OpenSSH in the windows server
and the client has a private key to connect to the server
it works fine if server time zone is UTC + (eg: Indian timezone)
and not work if the server time zone is UTC - (eg: USA timezones)

I use bellow Plink commnad

```
plink.exe -v workflow -P 22 -l administrator -N -i "C:\Program Files\RDC\private.ppk" -R 3391:127.0.0.1:3389
```

and it gives bellow out put when it is UTC + time zones
[image]

and when it is just change to UTC - time zone bellow error am getting

[image]

do anyone phase a similar issue and do we have a fix

Adding failed and success logs from sshd server-side

Success : [Success.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18S7o_-moCP5Dlu9pxb2NFSubyKC4jnmu/view?usp=sharing)
Failed: [Failed.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ytk6-vOpIZnesA8q_Lz8f_KSMS7GI75Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy and paste. You are making it just harder to help you.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have updated with added an error log as text file as well as a success log